# string regex vs array product catalog mongodb performance

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to implement a product catalog in mongodb but I am not sure should I use string to store product category which is regex friendly or should I prefer an array

eg:

```
{
  productId: 34523,
  name: "smartWatch",
  category: '/23425/6456/76556'
}
```

or

```
{
  productId: 34523,
  name: "smartWatch",
  category: [23425, 6456, 76556]
}
```

Comment: The only time i can think of the first structure being "better" is if there's an importance in the order of the numbers and you'll want to create -very- specific queries.

Comment: order is matter but only last and first category

Comment: the only concern for first case is whether I can use $lookup to fetch category info or not

Comment: I think the first structure will cause you a lot more issue's. remember you can always `$concat` the array before a lookup to it's original structure.

Comment: I just follow this amazing post https://dzone.com/articles/product-catalog-part-1-schema it's a little outdated but it's really amazing it used the first approach I don't know why ?

Comment: @Tom Slabbaert tnx alot

Comment: In the second structure, you can easily modify, where as in first structure, it's difficult.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB supports various query operators on arrays such as [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) and [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/). Trying to achieve the same functionality with regular expression searches would be much more awkward.

Answer (score 0):

The big issue with the second approach is that if we have "attributes" field then we can not use compound indexing.

eg:

```
{
  id: "2342342",
  name: "TV",
  categories: [234,345,456]
  attributes: [{name: "size", value: "wide"}, {name: "color", value: "black"}]
}
```

this

```
db.Product.createIndex({categories: 1, "attributes.name": 1})
```

will throw this error

```
cannot index parallel arrays [variants] [attributes]
```

or maybe using index intersection solve the issue